# My 7z File Changes Its Size After Uploading

Tags: linux

I have a compressed 7z file sized 914.3 MB. I found something odd after I upload it via ftp and cloud storage. The size changes to 872 MB. If I've done some research on search engine, also tried to reupload it several times. If you guys understand about this, Kindly explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you think it is a coincidence that is also the difference between the size in MB and the size in MiB? I.e. base 1000 vs base 1024 bytes.

Comment: OMG, I'm so sorry. It didn't notice that it was MiB. Those sounds new for me. Thank you ver much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jiggunjer is correct

**Short Answer:**

914.3MB == 871.9MiB

The [mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) (MiB) was designed as a replacement for the Megabyte (MB), and the the enterprise cloud storage you're uploading to likely uses it. Your workstation likely would not, hence the conversion.

[image: Converted Values]

**Links**

[Wikipedia - Binary prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)

[MB <-> MiB Converter](http://www.convertunits.com/from/MiB/to/megabyte).

**Additional Details:**

*What is the difference between 1 MiB and 1 MB?*

> The difference between 1 KiB and 1 KB is 1024−1000 bytes. The difference between 1 GiB and 1 GB is 1024<sup>3</sup>−1000<sup>3</sup> bytes.
>
> The "ibi" (or binary prefix) units (kibi, mebi, gibi) are based on 2<sup>10</sup> (1024), where the standard decimal units (kilo, mega, giga) are based on 10<sup>3</sup> (1000). Before the MiB was in use (I remember learning about it in school, circa 2002), MB often was ambiguous - was it binary or decimal? Often storage manufacturers would advertise using decimal, since 100GB is smaller than 100GiB (100GB is actually 93GiB and some change), while internally operating systems worked in binary units (the disk size and file size was always reported in GiB). Memory (RAM) manufacturers have always been using MiB/GiB, even though labeled "MB/GB".
> [Source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-1-MiB-and-1-MB-and-why-should-we-care)

Comment: Thanks man! This is my first question on this forum and I think it's also my first mistake. I have no basic understanding about digital storage measurement. I understand now. XD